# Summarize the list of the table in R

Tags: r

I have a list of data which I have represented here with dat. I am trying to summarize the data in a way that gives me the number of element in each list, along with unique elements and what's the frequency of each element (although in the example file there's 4 element, it can be much larger in the real file).

```
dat = list(c("a","b","c","d"),
           c("a","a"),
           c("b"),
           c("c","a","c"))

Num_element = sapply(dat, length)
Num_table = sapply(dat, table)
Num_unique = sapply(Num_table, length)
```

I am looking to get something of sort (which I know is wrong in many ways)

```
Summary_dat = cbind.data.frame(Num_element,Num_unique, Num_table)
```

Basically what I envision could be a nested dataframe, such that the output may look like:

```
  Num_element Num_unique  Num_table
1           4          4 a b c d 
2           2          1 1 1 1 1(in the same line as above)
3           1          1
4           3          2
```

I am not sure if it's possible to do what I am asking. If not, what will be a good way to represent the data, which can then also be exported to excel?

Comment: For `Num_element = sapply(dat, length)` you can use `Num_element = lengths(dat)` which is more efficient. My recommendation is to keep a second list of tables where the element position corresponds to the rwo the data.frame or element of the original list rather than this complex structure you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this is what you want?

```
data.frame(Num_element = Num_element,
           Num_unique = Num_unique,
           Num_table = sapply(Num_table, function(x) paste(names(x), x, collapse=' ')))

#  Num_element Num_unique       Num_table
#1           4          4 a 1 b 1 c 1 d 1
#2           2          1             a 2
#3           1          1             b 1
#4           3          2         a 1 c 2
```